# -bash ./foo: No such file or directory after compilation

Tags: c++, bash, gcc-warning

I'm compiling a program named benchmark_Quickthread_01.cpp:

```
#include <quickthread/QuickThread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace qt;

int main()
{
  qtInit qtInit( -1 );

  std::cout << "Blub\n" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

with  compiler options:

```
g++ -L /usr/local/lib64/ -static ./benchmark_Quickthread_01.cpp -lQuickThread 
-o qt.exe -pthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -lnuma -ldl -lrt -Wall
```

compiler gives no errors. However when I try running the file, bash gives me following error:

```
-bash: ./qt.exe: No such file or directory
```

File exists, I can ls, cat and check size ('du -h qt.exe' = 272K)

What might cause the problem?

Comment: run `ls -lah` on the terminal and write me the output

Comment: total 292K   
drwxr-xr-x 2 krzystof users 4.0K Aug 25 10:35 .   
drwxr-xr-x 5 krzystof users 4.0K Aug 25 09:58 ..   
-rw-r--r-- 1 krzystof users  168 Aug 25 09:58 benchmark_Quickthread_01.cpp
  **-rwxr-xr-x 1 krzystof users 275K Aug 25 10:35 qt**

Comment: @KostasRim extensions name don't matter in linux. You can run a `.exe` file in linux if it has been compiled on the system. The error may be linked with permission issues though. Try `chmod +x ./qt.exe`

Comment: @Aserre I did not know that you can run `.exe` files on Linux. Although I asked him to print the output of the command `ls -lah` so to check the permissions. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Does it have the executable bit(s) set? If not your file system may have been mounted with `noexec` or something similar, preventing g++ from setting the executable bit on the produced application.

Comment: @Elijan9 Yes, it does :)

Comment: For simplicity ... try running this ...  `g++ -L /usr/local/lib64/ -static ./benchmark_Quickthread_01.cpp -lQuickThread -pthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -lnuma -ldl -lrt -Wall`

Comment: What does `file ./qt` output? Is your g++ producing a binary you can't run?

Comment: @RafafTahsin - your command producec a.out. `./a.out` gives the same error
@Elijan9 - `./qt: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped`

Comment: And what does `ldd ./qt` output? You *are* running a 64-bit kernel (and bash), right? And what happens if you create and call a simple bash script, e.g. `echo "echo test" > ./test; chmod +x ./test; ./test`

Comment: `ldd ./qt` output: 
`linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe587b0000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f6f5db5e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (...)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (...)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (...)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (...)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (...)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (...)
    /lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (...)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (...)`

Comment: while `echo "echo test" > ./test; chmod +x ./test; ./test` prints out test.

Comment: compiling simple 'hello world' with same compiler flags runs correctly, So I think the problem might be the combination of `#include <Quickthread/Quickthread.h>` library and all those compiler flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-static` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` are conflicting.  Remove one or the other, and try again.